# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to xxx$LocalBinder

Tags: java, android, service

I am implementing a service and have a wrapper class on top of this service wich locally bind to it. Now when I export the service as a jar and link to it from another application (this application instantiate the wrapper class).
When I run the application, I am getting the ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to xxx$LocalBinder
caused by the local bind in the wrapper class:

```
service = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
```

The binder here is of type BinderProxy instead of localbinder and hence the crash.

The only way that this application works is when the package name of the app is the same as the service package name (I assume android thinks that the service is local).

```
private final IBinder localBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    xxxService getService() {
        return xxxService.this;
    }
}
```

and

```
public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ) {
    IBinder result = null;
    result = localbinder;
    return result;
}
```

Then in my wrapper class onServiceConnected:

```
    public void onServiceConnected( ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {   

         xxxService = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
```

Finally my wrapper class constructor:

```
public xxxServiceManager( Context context ) throws Exception {
    this.context = context;
    xxxServiceManagerIntent = new Intent( "providerAPI" );
    xxxServiceManagerIntent.setClassName( "com.yyy", "com.yyy.xxxService" );

    context.startService( xxxServiceManagerIntent );


    context.bindService( xxxServiceManagerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
```

Then in the main application that uses this jar, if you set the package name

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yyy.provider" //the same as the service (which does not make sense)
```

everything work, but obviously I want to set another package name.
Is there any way how to redesign or make this work?

thanks!

Comment: More source code will be helpful. Your service (especially the `onBind()` method and your `LocalBinder` class) and your binding code can reveal a lot about the cause of the problem.

Comment: It would be better to add your code to your original question. It would be way more readable and you won't need to worry about the char limit for comments.

Comment: Hopefully it's more clear now.. thanks for your help!!

Comment: Can you also post your service definition from the AndroidManifest? Are you, by any chance, starting the service in another process?

Comment: No, I am not starting the service in a different process.. here is the service declaration in the main application manifest :  <service
            android:name="com.yyy.xxxService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

Comment: the client which calls `bindService()` is hosted by different process than the `Service` it binds to, thats why you cannot use a "bound local service" pattern - you can verify that by logging `android.os.Process#myPid()` on both sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)

If your service is used only by the local application and does not need to work across processes, then you can implement your own Binder class that provides your client direct access to public methods in the service.

> Note: This works only if the client and service are in the same
>   application and process, which is most common. For example, this would
>   work well for a music application that needs to bind an activity to
>   its own service that's playing music in the background.